# Chromecast: How to clear receiver cache

Tags: google-cast

How do you ensure that the receiver is using the latest code deployed to the whitelisted url? Sometimes it appears to be using cached code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things you can do that should prevent it from caching:

1) With the receiver running in debug mode, visit your.chromecast.ip.address:9222 and load the developer tools. Click the 'settings' button (the gear) in the bottom-right of the dev tools window. In the settings pane, make sure the 'disable cache' box is checked.

2) In your receiver app, add a reference to a cache manifest:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/cast/js/receiver/1.0/cast_receiver.js">
</script>
.....
```

And a cache.manifest file that tells the chromecast's browser not to cache anything:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# Cache manifest version 1.0

CACHE

#no cache

NETWORK
*
```

Comment: Both of these make sense but I find that neither of them actually work 100% of the time... even physically unplugging the device sometimes fails to clear the browser cache.